# Applescript "expected end of line but found identifier" for terminal app

Tags: applescript

Complete noob here for `applescript`. I am wondering how to resolve following problem for the `applescript` shown below:

I get the following error on the line `tell the current terminal`:

[image]

`Expected end of line but identifier found`

[image]

Here is the code for anyone wishing to try it out:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    make new terminal
    tell the current terminal
        activate current session
        launch session "Default Session"
        tell the last session
            write text "unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ; unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
            write text "mkdir -p ~/.boot2docker"
            write text "if [ ! -f ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso ]; then cp /usr/local/share/boot2docker/boot2docker.iso ~/.boot2docker/ ; fi"
            write text "/usr/local/bin/boot2docker init && /usr/local/bin/boot2docker up && $(boot2docker shellinit) && docker version"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Reference:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-file-into-a-mac-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `terminal` term is an old **AppleScript** syntax.

Look at https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html for the new Applescript syntax.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set newWindow to (create window with default profile)
    tell newWindow
        tell current session
            write text "unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ; unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
            write text "mkdir -p ~/.boot2docker"
            write text "if [ ! -f ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso ]; then cp /usr/local/share/boot2docker/boot2docker.iso ~/.boot2docker/ ; fi"
            write text "/usr/local/bin/boot2docker init && /usr/local/bin/boot2docker up && $(boot2docker shellinit) && docker version"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```